# TaffyDB, filter the same field 2 times (greater then and less then)

Tags: javascript, taffydb

I would like to query a range in a TaffyDB (Greater then x but less then y). What I try is:

```
mydb({myvalue:{gt:2700},myvalue:{lt:3000}})
```

But for sure that can not work this way. The second myvalue just overrites the first one in the Object.

A work around would be to create the db-record with a cloned myvalue (=> myvalue1, myvalue2) and then query it this way:

```
mydb({myvalue1:{gt:2700},myvalue2:{lt:3000}})
```

But it would be a bit dirty.

Anyone got a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That works:

```
mydb({myvalue:{gt:2700}},{myvalue:{lt:3000}})
```